# how to get mapc to compile a mapping model

Tags: core-data-migration, xamarin.mac

We're successfully been using CoreData with Xamarin Studio, but I ran into a problem when trying to create a mapping model because we altered all the entities to subclass off of a single entity. I created the mapping model in Xcode as normal, but when I go to compile it using mapc like this:

xcrun mapc Model.xcmappingmodel .

this is the result:

mapc error - mapc failed to archive result to .

Of course I check and I do have write access to the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

First, do not extend all of your entities off a single entity.  That will create a very bad data model.  Guessing that you are using SQLite, that will produce a single table model that will perform poorly.

What happens when you try and compile your model directly in Xcode?